# Creating Groups based on Column Position

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

Good afternoon!

I think this is pretty straight forward question, but I think I am missing a couple of steps. Would like to create groups based on column position.

Am working with a dataframe / tibble; 33 rows long, and 66 columns wide.  However, every sequence of 6 columns, should really be separated into its own sub-dataframe / tibble.

The sequence of the number columns is arbitrary to the dataframe.  Below is an attempt with mtcars, where I am trying to group every 2 columns into its own sub-dataframe.

```
mtcars %>% 
  tibble() %>% 
  group_by(across(seq(1,2, length.out = 11))) %>% 
  nest()
```

However, that method generates errors.  Something similar applies when working just within nest() as well.

Using mtcars, would like to create groups using a sequence for every 3 columns, or some other number.

Would ultimately like the mtcars dataframe to be...

- Columns 1:3 to be group 1,
- Columns 4:6 to be group 2,
- Columns 7:9 to be group 3, etc... while retaining the information for the rows in each column.

Also considered something with pivot_longer...

```
mtcars %>% 
  tibble() %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = seq(1,3, by = 1))
```

...but that did not generate defined groups, or continue the sequencing along all columns of the dataframe.

Hope one of you can help me with this! Would make certain tasks for work much easier.

PS - A plus if you can keep the workflow to tidyverse centric code :)

Comment: What do you mean with “group”? A separate data frame-column? What should be the name of these columns?

Comment: By "group" I meant a a list of dataframes, with every 3 columns being one of the dataframes. The name did not really matter to me, group 1 or just 1 is fine.  The solution offered below worked very well for me, though I really thought it would take fewer steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this. It splits the dataframe into a list of dataframes based on the number of columns you want (3 in your example):

```r
library(tidyverse)

list_of_dataframes <- mtcars %>%
  tibble() %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-row) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  mutate(group = ceiling(row_number()/ 3)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_split(group) %>%
  map(
    ~select(.x, row, name, value) %>%
      pivot_wider()
    )
```

****EDIT****

Here, based on comments from the question asker, we will avoid pivoting the data. Instead, we map the groups across the dataframe.

```r
list_of_dataframes <- map(seq(1, ncol(mtcars), by = 3),
     ~mtcars %>%
       as_tibble() %>%
       select(all_of(.x:min(c(.x+2, ncol(mtcars))))))
```

We can then wrap this in a function to make it a little easier to use and change group sizes and dataframes:

```r
group_split_cols <- function(.data, ncols_per_group){
  map(seq(1, ncol(.data), by = ncols_per_group),
     ~.data %>%
       as_tibble() %>%
       select(all_of(.x:min(c(.x+ncols_per_group-1, ncol(.data))))))
}


list_of_dataframes <- group_split_cols(.data = mtcars, ncols_per_group = 3)
```

Comment: That is a clever solution!  Pretty sure I can apply that method to the larger dataset.  Kind of surprised it took pivoting longer really.....really thought the process could be done in a select() or group_by() %>% nest() process.  Either way, thank you!

Comment: @JamesCrumpler we can definitely make that happen. I just needed to think a little harder. Check out the updates to my answer.